# Password generator - nested while loop

Tags: python

I am working on the below password generator and an issue that baffles me.

There's a nested while loop which asks the user if they would like to select a new password after one is generated. Each time you selected "Yes", it should ideally generate a new password to replace the old one. It is not the case, with every re-selection, it adds a new password to the old one.

What am I not doing right here?

```
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits

special_chars = "!#$%&*@^"
available_chars = list(ascii_lowercase) + list(ascii_uppercase) + list(digits) + list(special_chars)


def get_length():
    user_l = ""
    while not user_l.isdigit() or int(user_l) < 6:
        user_l = input("Please input a password length.\n")
    return int(user_l)
    print(int(user_l))

def pwd_gen(length):
    return [random.choice(available_chars) for i in range(length)]


def pwd_chk(length):
    pwd = []
    while True:
        pwd = pwd_gen(length)
        if set(pwd) & set(ascii_lowercase) == set():
            continue
        elif set(pwd) & set(ascii_uppercase) == set():
            continue
        elif set(pwd) & set(digits) == set():
            continue
        elif set(pwd) & set(special_chars) == set():
            continue
        else:
            print("\nYour password is " + "".join(pwd))
            while True:
                accept = input("Would you like a different password? Y/N\n\n")
                if accept.lower() == "n" or accept.lower() == "no":
                    print("\nYour password is:")
                    break
                elif accept.lower() == "y" or accept.lower() == "yes":
                    pwd_chk(length)
                    break
                else:
                    print("\nInvalid input. Your password is " + "".join(pwd))
                    continue
            break

    pwd = "".join(pwd)
    print(pwd)

pwd_chk(get_length())
```

Comment: Calling itself recursively each time the user accepts doesn't make sense.  The stack keeps growing for no reason.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you may want to consider simplifying some of your if/else statements by joining conditions, like the first one can turn into `if not set(pwd) or not (set(ascii_lowercase) == set() | set(ascii_uppercase) == set() | set(digits) == set() | set(special_chars) == set()):`. You can then get rid of all the `continue` statements.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks Tom. How do you get rid of recursive calls and still get the program to regenerate a password?

Comment: @LCY Instead of calling itself recursively, just have it loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not stopping the loop after you choose "Y", so the unfinished functions continue their execution. By using a `return` statement (rather than `break`) you stop the function from printing the password it generated.

```py
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits

special_chars = "!#$%&*@^"
available_chars = list(ascii_lowercase) + list(ascii_uppercase) + list(digits) + list(special_chars)


def get_length():
    user_l = ""
    while not user_l.isdigit() or int(user_l) < 6:
        user_l = input("Please input a password length.\n")
    return int(user_l)
    print(int(user_l))

def pwd_gen(length):
    return [random.choice(available_chars) for i in range(length)]


def pwd_chk(length):
    pwd = []
    while True:
        pwd = pwd_gen(length)
        if set(pwd) & set(ascii_lowercase) == set():
            continue
        elif set(pwd) & set(ascii_uppercase) == set():
            continue
        elif set(pwd) & set(digits) == set():
            continue
        elif set(pwd) & set(special_chars) == set():
            continue
        else:
            print("\nYour password is " + "".join(pwd))
            while True:
                accept = input("Would you like a different password? Y/N\n\n")
                if accept.lower() == "n" or accept.lower() == "no":
                    print("\nYour password is:")
                    break
                elif accept.lower() == "y" or accept.lower() == "yes":
                    pwd_chk(length)
                    return # CHANGE THIS FROM "break" TO "return"! #
                else:
                    print("\nInvalid input. Your password is " + "".join(pwd))
                    continue
            break

    pwd = "".join(pwd)
    print(pwd)

pwd_chk(get_length())
```

As a side note, you shouldn't use the default random module to generate passwords if you will actually be using them. It is safer to use the `secrets` module, or seed the random number generator with

```py
import os
import random
random.seed(os.urandom(16))
```

to achieve security.

Comment: +1 for the side note. Returning after the recursive call will solve the printing issue, but as Tom Karzes commented, it's better not to make the recursive call anyway, since the stack will grow without much benefit. The answer posted by Sebastian starts to address this issue.

Comment: Thank you all ! I find the forum more amazing than the coding itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a flag instead of invoking the function again (code of inner while):

```
            while True:
                replace_password = False # Flag added here
                accept = input("Would you like a different password? Y/N\n\n")
                if accept.lower() == "n" or accept.lower() == "no":
                    print("\nYour password is:")
                    break
                elif accept.lower() == "y" or accept.lower() == "yes":
                    replace_password = True # Setting flag
                    break
                else:
                    print("\nInvalid input. Your password is " + "".join(pwd))
                    continue
            if replace_password: # Action based on flag
                continue
            break
```

Comment: This code still calls pwd_chk again, seemingly at odds with your proposal. Is that intentional?

Comment: Sorry for that it should not be there. That's probably enough stack for today...